# Как из всего текста выбрать только нужное?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, json

Из текста:

```
{"result":  [{"spa_id":153048737,"mmr":354.727809161879,"season_number":43,"calibrationBattlesLeft":0,"number":1,"skip":false,"updated_at":"2022-12-18 12:50:57","score":6547,"nickname":"Luc1que_","clan_tag":"PWNZ"}
```

нужно отобразить только clan_tag, nickname и score

как это сделать?

Comment: почитайте про json

Comment: В вопросе json корявый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если исходник такой:

```py
data = {"result":
{"spa_id": 153048737, "mmr": 354.727809161879, "season_number": 43, "calibrationBattlesLeft": 0, "number": 1, "skip": False, "updated_at": "2022-12-18 12:50:57", "score": 6547, "nickname": "Luc1que_", "clan_tag": "PWNZ"}}
```

ТО примерно так:

```py
print(data["result"]["clan_tag"])
print(data["result"]["nickname"])
print(data["result"]["score"])
```

Comment: да сработало, спасибо