# Как из словаря питона выбрать только нужные значения

Tags: python, json

Из запроса сайта я получаю ответ и преобразую его в словарь питона.

```
r = requests.get('https://tanksblitz.ru/ru/api/rating-leaderboards/league/0/top/')
data = r.json()
```

И получаю следующее:

> {'result': [{'spa_id': 153048737, 'mmr': 355.928166286089, 'season_number': 43, 'calibrationBattlesLeft': 0, 'number': 1, 'skip': False, 'updated_at': '2022-12-18 14:20:44', 'score': 6559, 'nickname': 'Luc1que_', 'clan_tag': 'PWNZ'}

Как сделать чтобы выводилось только clan_tag, nickname и score все в строчку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478899/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из всего текста выбрать только нужное?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478899/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Comment: print(*(f"clan_tag = {x['clan_tag']} nickname={x['nickname']} score={x['score']}" for x in data['result']), sep='\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
for d in data['result']:
    print(d['clan_tag'])
```